# stream reduction incompatible types

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I'm trying to create a finder which takes several predicates and reduces them:

```
public static <T extends BusinessInterface> Collection<T> findOr(
    Context pContext, Class<T> pClass, Predicate<? super T>... pPredicates) {
  Predicate<? super T> lReducedPredicate =
      Arrays.asList(pPredicates).stream().reduce(Predicate::or).orElse(r -> false);
  return find(pContext, pClass, lReducedPredicate);
}
```

Unfortunately I get following compiler error:

> Predicate lReducedPredicate = Arrays.asList(pPredicates).stream().reduce(Predicate::or).orElse(r -> false);
>   incompatible types: Predicate cannot be converted to Predicate
>   where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends BusinessInterface declared in method findOr(Context,Class,Predicate...)
>   where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
>   CAP#1 extends Object super: T from capture of ? super T
>   CAP#2 extends Object super: T from capture of ? super T

I get not errors in Eclipse and I have no idea what is going wrong.

Any help is really appreciated :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to solve this is using

```
public static <T extends BusinessInterface> Collection<T> findOr(
    Context pContext, Class<T> pClass, Predicate<? super T>... pPredicates) {
  Predicate<? super T> lReducedPredicate = Arrays.asList(pPredicates).stream()
    .reduce((a,b) -> t -> a.test(t) || b.test(t)).orElse(r -> false);
  return find(pContext, pClass, lReducedPredicate);
}
```

While you can’t invoke the `or` method on a `Predicate<? super T>` instance with another `Predicate<? super T>` as argument, you can create the same function, `or` would return, yourself, as passing a `T` instance to either `test` method is valid.

Answer (score 6):

Your code works for me in intellij, but not in ideone, which is strange.

The reason for the compiler error is that you're effectively trying to do this:

```
Predicate<? super T> a = null;
Predicate<? super T> b = null;
a.or(b);  // Compiler error!
```

Because of the separate wildcards on both `a` and `b`, the compiler can't guarantee that the type bounds are compatible, because those wildcards are not necessarily the same.

Anyway, try this one weird trick:

```
Arrays.asList(pPredicates)
    .stream()
    .map(a -> a)  // Here!
    .reduce(Predicate::or)
    .orElse(r -> false);
```

Inserting this line allows it to cast to the type which matches the type constraints.

Comment: @Holger I don't have a good explanation. My intuition is that it gives the type inference logic just a bit more flexibility to choose a type which is compatible with the `reduce(Predicate::or)`. I'd be delighted if you could explain it without my handwaving ;)

Comment: I'd be interested in the answer as well :). With `.map(a ->a)` I don't get any compiler errors anymore and the unit-tests are working as expected. So, is there any reason to choose Holgers solution prior to Andys?

Comment: @user1567896: the main reason to prefer my answer would be that we know why it works. As long as we don’t know why the `map(a -> a)` trick works, we have to consider that this could be just a compiler bug that gets fixed in a newer version. A cleaner alternative still using `Predicate::or` would be `Predicate<T> lReducedPredicate = Arrays.asList(pPredicates).stream() .reduce(r -> false, Predicate::or, Predicate::or);`

Comment: @Holger blimey, if even *you* can't explain it, it is worth staying away from it. I really was hoping to be enlightened.

Comment: @Holger I've posted [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935248/why-does-adding-mapa-a-allow-this-to-compile) asking about this specifically.