# Why can't Java typecheck this code?

Tags: java, generics, typechecking

I have some stream handling code that takes a stream of words and performs some operations on them, then reduces them to a `Map` containing the words as keys and the number of occurrences of the word as a `Long` value.  For the sake of the brevity of the code, I used the [jOOL library](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL)'s [`Seq`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.9/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html) class, which contains a number of useful shortcut methods.

The code compiles just fine if I write it like this:

```
item.setWordIndex (
        getWords (item)                      // returns a Seq<String>
              .map (this::removePunctuation) // String -> String
              .map (stemmer::stem)           // String -> String
              .groupBy(str -> str, Collectors.counting ()));
```

However, if I attempt to replace the `str -> str` lambda with the more self-documenting `Function::identity`, I get the following errors:

> The method `setWordIndex(Map<String,Long>)` in the type `MyClass` is not applicable for the arguments `(Map<Object,Long>)`
>   The type `Function` does not define `identity(String)` that is applicable here

Why does `Function::identity` behave any differently to `str -> str`, which I (perhaps naively) assumed was directly equivalent, and why can't the compiler handle it when it is used?

(And yes, I'm aware I could remove the identity function by moving the previous `map` application into the `groupBy` operation, but I find the code clearer like this, because it follows the application logic more directly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 lambdas, Function.identity() or t->t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t)

Comment: You want `Function.identity()` rather than `Function::identity`.

Comment: @NimrodArgov - that question asks which is preferable in cases where both work, rather than why `Function::identity` doesn't work in this specific case.

Comment: This reminds me of [a question I asked a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44935248/3788176). Perhaps the compiler options I mention there will give some useful insight?

Comment: @AndyTurner - That's interesting.  I'm guessing the logic here is working on similar lines, but I can't quite figure out how.

Comment: Can you simplify your example? Or make it more easily reproducible at least without jool: does the same happen with `Arrays.asList("").stream().groupBy(...)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `Function.identity()` (which returns a `Function<T, T>`), not `Function::identity` (which matches the SAM type `Supplier<Function<T, T>>`).

The following code compiles fine:

```
static String removePunctuation(String x) { return x; }
static String stem(String x) { return x; }

// ...

final Map<String, Long> yeah = Seq.of("a", "b", "c")
        .map(Test::removePunctuation)
        .map(Test::stem)
        .groupBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting());
```

Comment: Ah, yes.  Makes sense now I look at it again. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference between the two types; they are not directly equivalent:

- `Function.identity()` has to return the input type, because its type is `Function<T, T>`;
- `str -> str` can return a wider type; effectively it is `Function<? extends T, T>`.

Comment: While this is true, I don't understand how it is relevant here: the correct type that makes the code work is `Function<String,String>`, so the necessity for a wider type doesn't seem to be there?

Comment: @Jules I am merely pointing out that they are not directly equivalent.