# Wrapping a contravariant functional interface without losing genericity

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I have some code with this general structure:

```
interface Func<A> {
    double apply(Optional<A> a);
}

class Foo {
    public double compute(Func<Double> f) {
        // Sometimes amend the function to do something slightly different
        Func<Double> g = f;
        if (someCondition())
            g = oa -> Math.max(0, f.apply(oa));

        return g.apply(Optional.of(3.14)) + g.apply(Optional.empty());
    }
}
```

This, in itself, works well enough. Now I want to be more liberal such that if someone has, say, a `Func<Number>` or `Func<Object>` instead of a `Func<Double>` they can still pass that into `compute`. *A priori* this ought to be safe enough. Very well, so I change it to

```
    public double compute(Func<? super Double> f) {
        Func<? super Double> g = f;
        if (someCondition())
            g = oa -> Math.max(0, f.apply(oa));
        ...
```

Unfortunately now the lambda doesn't typecheck (says Eclipse) because the type of `oa` cannot be passed to `f.apply`.

The assignment of `f` itself to `g` doesn't seem to worry the compiler, and the problem does not arise if the argument to `apply` is `A` rather than `Optional<A>`.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to *name* the `? super Double` argument type so I can use it again as the type for `g` and/or replace the lambda with an old-fashioned inner class.

For example, this is not even syntactically allowed:

```
    public <T super Double> double compute(Func<T> f) {
        Func<T> g = f;
        ...
```

**Is there any reasonably elegant way to make this work?**

The best I've come up with so far is

```
    public double compute(Func<? super Double> f) {
        if (someCondition())
            return computeInner(oa -> Math.max(0, f.apply(oa)));
        else
            return computeInner(f);
    }

    private double computeInner(Func<? super Double> g) {
        return g.apply(Optional.of(3.14)) + g.apply(Optional.empty());
    }
```

The compiler accepts this, but the indirect call for no other reason than to make the type checker happy is not really what I'd call elegant.

Comment: This isn't related to your issue, but if you use java.util.function.Function instead of yours, you can do `f.andThen(a -> Math.max(0, a))`

Comment: @killjoy: I first tried to minimize the example down to `Function`, but the problem only arises if the interface _itself_ supplies the `Optional` wrapper in the argument types. (The actual code I'm looking at has a bunch of additional parameters to the function that are not relevant for the question).

Comment: You can use `Number.doubleValue()` instead of unboxing normally.

Comment: @killjoy: That doesn't help if someone has a `Func<Object>` they want to pass.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one weird trick:

```
g = oa -> Math.max(0, f.apply(oa.map(a -> a)));
                             // ^----------^
```

Mapping the type of the optional like this allows the compiler to "cast" the type of the optional to a consistent type.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/4Xoz8E)

This does have the downside of creating a new `Optional` instance.

---

But, of course, [I asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935248/why-does-adding-mapa-a-allow-this-to-compile) which ponders whether this is actually something that is intended to be allowed by the spec, or a bug.

---

Personally, I don't find your "best so far" particularly egregious. Of course, it depends on how the real code looks with it.

Comment: Ah, I've had to use that hack before; but its only possible because of the API that the `Optional` provides. For cases where we have no transformation API available I wonder if there's a more *generic* pattern to follow ;)

Answer (score 1):

In general I find type inference for super bounds in Java to be a nightmare.. there are many compiler bugs and it's generally hard to reason around why the compiler will reject a certain syntax and not others.

That said, you can get around this in a hackish way by casting `f` to a `Func<Double>` type. This is not exactly a safe cast; if `f` had any state, we might assume that the lower bound on `f` is `Double` when in reality it could be `Number` or `Object`. With the cast, you don't incur the performance penalty of the solution provided by @AndyTurner, but unchecked casts are also not your friend.

```
public double compute(Func<? super Double> f) {
    // Sometimes amend the function to do something slightly different
    Func<? super Double> g = f;
    if (someCondition())
        g = oa -> Math.max(0, (((Func<Double>) f)).apply(oa));

    return g.apply(Optional.of(3.14)) + g.apply(Optional.empty());
}
```

All in all, I would consider the solution you presented in the question to be the best solution to the problem. It is a little more verbose, but the compiler should be able to optimize the code. You don't lose compile time safety with unchecked casts, and you don't introduce run time degradation due to the creation of additional `Optional` instances.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is change your interface signature:

```
double apply(Optional<? extends A> a);
```

### Analysis

Consider if your interface is simply:

```
double apply(A a);
```

Then never error will happen.

It's because `Double` is assignable to `Object`. Compiler will auto adapt the type. That means the interface in fact is:

```
double apply(? extends A a);
```

So what you need do is let your interface has this adapt ability.

`func(Number)` can accept `Double` as parameter.

`func(Optional<Number>)` should accept `Optional<Double>` as well.

So you should add the `? extends` on your inteface.